# How many functions $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ are there that satisfy the equation

Tags: combinatorics

How many functions $f: A \rightarrow  \mathbb{N}$ are there with $A:= \{1,\dots,5\}$ where the following equation is satisfied:

$$f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(4) + f(5) = 20$$

- How can I find the number of functions that fit this question? The only principle of counting functions I know is counting the number of functions between two finite sets so I am unsure if I can apply any of that here

Comment: There is a related question (not quite a duplicate) [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/91733/1508).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the set of all $5$-tuples $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)$ that satisfy:
$$
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 15
$$
where for each $i \in \{1, \ldots, 5\}$, we have that $x_i$ is a **nonnegative** integer (so that $x_i$ could be zero). Then:
\begin{align*}
f(1) &= 1 + x_1 \\
f(2) &= 1 + x_2 \\
f(3) &= 1 + x_3 \\
f(4) &= 1 + x_4 \\
f(5) &= 1 + x_5 \\
\end{align*}
defines a unique function $f\colon A \to \mathbb N$ that satisfies the given equation. Now to count such $5$-tuples, we use a stars-and-bars argument. There is a one-to-one correspondence between such $5$-tuples and strings of $15$ stars and $5 - 1 = 4$ bars; for example, $(3, 0, 5, 5, 2)$ corresponds to:
$$
\star \star \star \mid \mid \star \star \star \star \star \mid \star \star \star \star \star \mid \star \star
$$
The number of strings of such stars-and-bars is precisely:
$$
\binom{19}{15} = \frac{19!}{15!4!} = 3876
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Your functions $f$ are supposed to go in $\mathbb{N}$. But what happens if for some $i$, $f(i)>20$ ? Deduce from your answer to this question that your are looking for functions from $A$ to $\{1,...,20\}$ and then apply your knowledge about counting functions between two finite sets.

Comment: But it states that A must be {1..5}?

Comment: There are $20^5$ functions from $A$ to $\{1,\ldots,20\}$, but what does that have to do with this problem?

Comment: Indeed, I dont get the point of this answer

Comment: @TonyK, well from what I have read in the question :"the only principle of counting functions I know is counting the number of functions between two finite sets so I am unsure if I can apply any of that here", the problem faced is that functions are going to $\mathbb{N}$ and not to a finite set. I have just said that there is no problem because  $\mathbb{N}$ can easily replaced by $\{1,...,20\}$. Then it just reduces to "how to make $20$ summing $5$ integers" which is an easy problem (assumed to be known in my answer, BTW +1 to Adriano).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of positive integers, in particular $0\notin \mathbb{N}$.. Hence, we are searching for how many (ordered) 5-uples (a,b,c,d,e) of positive integers are such that
$$
a+b+c+d+e=20.
$$
Suppose we have 20 consecutive boxes. Choosing 4 of them, *and noone of them being the first one,* we have a 1-1 bijection with the ordered solution of the equation. Therefore the answer is
$$\binom{19}{4}.$$

Comment: Why choose 4? or are you just using it as an example and in this case I would choose 5?

Comment: it is not a mistake: when you choose 4 boxes, then automatically you divide the 20boxes into 5 consecutive groups ;)

Comment: This answer is wrong.

Comment: What should be the answer?

Comment: See Adriano's answer. You can see that this answer is wrong by substituting $5$ for $20$: your method would give $\binom{5}{4}=5$, but the correct answer is $\binom{4}{4}=1$.

Comment: Oh right, the first one cannot be chosen. Otherwise a group can be empty.

Comment: Anyway, even if the idea is similar, Adriano's answer is quite different since it assumes $x_i$ to be non-negative, which is a known case..

Comment: Here is another way of solving the problem in the positive integers.  We have $20$ ones.  There are $19$ spaces between them.  A particular solution corresponds to a choice of which $4$ of the $19$ spaces to fill with addition signs.  For instance, $1 1 + 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1$ corresponds to the solution $a = 2$, $b = 4$, $c = 6$, $d = 1$, and $e = 7$.  Therefore, there are $\binom{19}{4}$ solutions of the equation $a + b + c + d + e = 20$ in the positive integers.